# How to create a matrix with averages of pairs of elements of a vector, efficiently

Tags: matrix, vector, average

I have:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

I want to obtain a matrix `a_avg`, where `a_avg[i,j]` is the average of `a[i]` and `a[j]`, efficiently (without using loops), such that the result is:

```
np.array([[1.,  1.5, 2. ],
          [1.5, 2.,  2.5],
          [2.,  2.5, 3. ]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
a_avg = (a[:, np.newaxis] + a) / 2
```

(I did not find this question online, so I thought it could be useful to share)